# PHP how to not refresh input values after press submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have problem, when I press submit button in my contact form all input values refreshing, it's good if all fields are filled correct, but if are some warning users must see previaus values, but all are cleared. My Javascript skills are low, maye are solution to solv this problem with php and html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simpler way is use html5  storage . store value on onkeyup event and destroy if submit successful

for an example

```
 <input id="title"   type="text" value=""  name="article_name">
```

script

to check support of html5

```
 function supports_html5_storage() {
          try {
            return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
          } catch (e) {
            return false;
          }
        }
```

script to store

```
  if(supports_html5_storage()){

        $("#title").keyup(function(){

            var articel_title =  $("#title").val();
             localStorage.setItem("articel_title",articel_title);
             localStorage.getItem("articel_title");
        });
```

to clear storage ,you can fire this if form successfully submit it will clear storage

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
          localStorage.removeItem("articel_title");

     </script>
```

you can also make ajax call on change or keyup event and store value to database so that if html5 is not supported by browser it will still work but it will cause more load on server

Answer (score 1):

return values to client:

```
<input type="text" name="val1" value="<?echo $_POST['val1']?>" />
```

Comment: Ok, but what to do first time, when submit button is pressed 0 times ?

Comment: And second question what to do with `select`

Answer (score 1):

Post your values to an iframe within the page and if the entries are correct then redirect to another page.

So if the entries are wrong you would not have to do anything

Answer (score 0):

You will need [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). The follwoing tutorials will help you:

- http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery
- http://www.tuttoaster.com/create-an-ajaxjqueryphp-contact-form/