# accidentally reloading the page should keep the value of the input fields PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, cookies

I have a form in html and when the visitor of the website starts typing in the input fields
(name, adress, mail, ...) and he/she fills in for example

name: John Smith and than reloads the page, it still needs to be filled in with John Smith.

I have to do this with php with sessions, can someone help me?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669385/php-how-to-not-refresh-input-values-after-press-submit/13669401#13669401

Comment: Sounds like homework... Also, do you mean if they /submit/ the page (and it fails) or they just refresh the page manually?

Comment: Yeah, it is homework but i can't figure it out. It has to remember it when they refresh manually, i already know how to save the data after submitting but in this case they don't submit.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. Saying that, personally, if they don't submit (and hit back or whatever), I wouldn't bother trying to store the data.

Comment: I sensed its a homework too, so I didn't write any code for @AxelLambregts .  I think the direction is enough for him as a push and he should complete it himself.

Comment: I understand it and hope i can complete it. Thanks for the support and giving a push. I really like to learn all this but the teacher who gives php doesn't learn us anything and says we should use php.net and find it out alone. By doing it i will learn it but i still think that's not a perfect way to learn something to your students. And thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html5 local storage or if you have to do this with sessions, you will have to fire up numerous AJAX requests upon each field change.

This is going to be tricky: if you want to save the values on each "change", you will be sending an AJAX request on each keystroke.  The timing synchronization is going to fail and you may lose some characters at some time.

I would suggest saving the values at a specific time interval or a more delayed event like when input controls are losing focus, they can send a value to the server for saving in the session.  On page generation, use session object to load values on controls.